# Linux Mint 18.3 touchpad middle click

Tags: linux-mint, xorg, touchpad

I just installed Mint 18.3 and I'm trying to set my touchpad to do a middle click for a 2-finger tap and a right click for a 3-finger tap. Running

```
synclient TapButton2=2
synclient TapButton3=3
```

works (until X11 is restarted).

I tried adding a `10-synaptics.conf` file to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` to make these settings permanent, but that doesn't seem to have any effect. Here're the contents of the file:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    Option "TapButton1" "1"
    Option "TapButton2" "2"
    Option "TapButton3" "3"
    Option "VertTwoFingerScroll"  "on"
    Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "off"
    Option "HorizEdgeScroll" "off"
    Option "VertEdgeScroll"  "off"
EndSection
```

In `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` I have:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this done differently in mint 18.3?

There's also a `Mouse Preferences` GUI that has options for multi-finger clicks, but changing that doesn't affect anything.

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact answer but a way to have middle click.

My device is detected as "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad". I have an ASUS laptop model X550LA. I managed to configure a middle click by assigning an exclusive portion my touchpad, right in the middle of left button and right button.

The command is:

```
xinput set-prop "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" "Synaptics Soft Button Areas" 1950 0 1823 0 1300 1917 1823 0
```

You can find a detailed explanation on what each number means here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Buttonless_touchpads_.28aka_ClickPads.29
There you'll find a very short mention to x-axis and y-axis ranges. This is how I calculated my settings:

```
$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep y-axis
[    38.532] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: y-axis range 0 - 2223 (res 33)
$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep y-axis
[    38.532] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: x-axis range 0 - 3249 (res 33)
```

Another very important detail is what axis range to use for each setting. For RightButtonArea**Left** use x-axis, for RightButtonArea**Top** use y-axis, for MiddleButtonArea**Left** use x-axis, and so on.

I'm still figuring out how to make this setting permanent.